# How to check end element with empty tag on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xml, nsxmlparser

I'm newbie on iPhone development.I want to parse XML file like this to get attribute value.

```
   <Root>
         <element att_1 ="value1" att_2 ="value2" />
         <element att_1 ="value1" att_2 ="value2" />
                             .
                             .
                             .

   <Root/>
```

Normally XML file

```
   <element att="..."> content <element/>
```

I use this at didEndElement

```
   if([elementName isEqualToString:@"element"]){

   // Do something

   }
```

How to check empty tag ? Advice me Please.
Thank you.

sorry for my bad english.

=====================================================================

Now I have new problem.when I run the application(simulator) it stuck and show message"Thread1:Stopped at breakpoint" in didStartElement.I guess I do something wrong.

StudyList.xml

```
    <StudyList>
           <study description="20040311181130" modsInStudy="" pat_birth="19760822" pat_id="47-3450" pat_name="Ekachai Chaichanasiri" refPhy="" study_date="Sun Jan 11 00:03:00 ICT 2004"  study_id="696122224" study_iuid="1.2.392.200036.9123.100.200.20040311181130"/>
           <study description="XoranCAT Study" modsInStudy="" pat_birth="19821117" pat_id="63" pat_name="Wantana Areeprayolkij" refPhy="" study_date="Fri Jan 28 00:04:00 ICT 2005" study_id="" study_iuid="1.2.826.0.1.3680043.2.594.4041.16900.9840.32723.30648"/>
    </StudyList>
```

Delegate

```
    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{


    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"StudyList"]) {
    //Initialize the array.
    appDelegate.studyList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"study"]) {
    //Initialize the study.
    aStudy.patientBrith = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"pat_birth"] ;
    aStudy.patientID = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"pat_id"];
    aStudy.patientName = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"pat_name"];
    aStudy.studyDate = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"study_date"];


    NSLog(@"Patient name: %@",aStudy.patientName);
    NSLog(@"Patient ID: %@",aStudy.patientID);
    NSLog(@"Patient Birth: %@" ,aStudy.patientBrith);
    NSLog(@"Study Date: %@" ,aStudy.studyDate);

        }
    NSLog(@"Process Element");
    }
    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    //Nothing to do because XML file dose not have text node

    }

    -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    //End if XML file nothing to do.
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"StudyList"]) {
    return;

    //Add study object in to array and release the object.

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@""]||elementName == nil) {
        [appDelegate.studyList addObject:aStudy];
          }
        }
    }
```

NSLog(@"Patient name: %@",aStudy.patientName);

NSLog(@"Patient ID: %@",aStudy.patientID);

NSLog(@"Patient Birth: %@" ,aStudy.patientBrith);

NSLog(@"Study Date: %@" ,aStudy.studyDate);

***Output of above is null.
What wrong,Please tell me in right way.

Comment: You might want to accept answers to your previous questions, if you expect ppl to help you.

Comment: If someone answers a question you've asked, an outline of a checkmark will appear beside the answer. You can click on that to "accept" an answer as the one that best solved your problem. This alerts others of the answer likely to help them, awards reputation points to the person who took the time to answer your question, and is generally a good way to support the SO community. You may want to go back through your previous 9 questions to see if there is one that really helped, and "accept" it.

Comment: Thank for advice.I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Retain the value of string in this function

```
 - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

In `- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName`
Check

```
if ([retainedString isEqualToString:@"" ] || [retainString == nil)
```

Then the value is empty.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Now I have new problem in update question.Help me please.

Comment: Remove the break point from xcode, Right click on that line and delete breakpoint.